# groupby agg with first non-null unique value

Tags: pandas

Following code gives error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":['a','a','b'],"item1":['b','d','c']})

df.groupby("item").agg(model_list=("item1", np.unique))
```

Since there are two unique values for item `a` (i.e., `b` and `d`), how to modify it to return the first non-null unique value?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) which by default remove missing values, so returned first non missing value:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":['a','a','b','b','b'],"item1":['b','d',np.nan, np.nan, 'c']})
        

df = df.groupby("item").agg(model_list=("item1", 'first'))
print (df)
     model_list
item           
a             b
b             c
```

Comment: i am getting this error when i ran this code. TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'